# How to reference projects (with a mix of nuget and project reference) and settle conflicting requests between their dependencies (NU1106)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dependencies, nuget

I'm having some issues trying to reference a project in order to access Events objects defined in it.

Project **A** and **B** are windows services. B can run without A but A needs B.
Project A needs a reference to project B to access event object. those events are serialized and sent through MQTT from project A to be processed by project B
Project B listen for Events and execute them.

I use nuget packages that might be common in both projec (seems to be the issue here)

When I Add a reference to project B in project A (not through nuget, but with a direct project reference) I get the Error **NU1106 : Unable to satisfy conflicting requests...**

I cannot find a satisfying solution to this.
I know that i can create a project C with the events without any dependencies and reference this project by both A and B. But I don't want to create multiple projects for each service.

*edit: Or is this  (multiplying projects) the philosophy of how thing are done with c# and nuget and I should just accept it ?*

Is there any way to reference project B Events without causing conflicts  ? Especially since I don't care about project B dependencies since the Event classes will not use them.

**What I tried : **

Adding project reference to project B in project A.
Finding properties in the project reference that would allow to settle the conflicting request.

**result expected : **

no NU1106, access to the public classes from B in A.

project file of Project A:

```
 <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Worker">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <UserSecretsId>dotnet-Projects.Robinson.RobinsonService-ea21e162-c9d3-4081-9f20-7ff9f64d2fe5</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Services.Mqtt" Version="1.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="6.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="6.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices" Version="6.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions" Version="6.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog" Version="2.12.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Extensions.Hosting" Version="5.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Extensions.Logging" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Settings.Configuration" Version="3.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Console" Version="4.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Debug" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.File" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Stateless" Version="5.13.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\..\Applications\Applications.ScannerProcess\Applications.ScannerProcess.csproj" />
   
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\..\Services\Service.Ftp\Service.Ftp.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\..\Services\Services.Opcua\Services.Opcua.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Projects.Robinson\Projects.Robinson.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Devices\Robot\Communications\" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Error during build is a very long list of NU1106 errors (140)

and

Error   MSB4018 The "ResolvePackageDependencies" task failed unexpectedly.
System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.
at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add) at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageDependencies.GetPackageAndFileDependencies(LockFileTarget target)
at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageDependencies.RaiseLockFileTargets()
at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageDependencies.ExecuteCore()
at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.TaskBase.Execute()
at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext() Projects.Robinson.RobinsonService   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.103\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets    195

Comment: What did the ellipsis omit?

Comment: Please add the .csproj files and the full error text. A full [mre] would be great also.